# ffmpeg stops generating mp4 ~1.5 seconds before end

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I'm no ffmpeg expert. I'm trying to generate a video with a matching image overlapped on top to create a cinemagraph effect. For the basic test I run this, but it stops creating frames about 1.5 seconds before the end of the output video is complete.

`ffmpeg -ss 10.0000 -t 15.00000 -i waterfall.mp4 -loop 1 -i output.png -an output1.mp4`

Could anyone point me in the right direction for why this might be occurring? All help is appreciated!

Comment: This question belongs on SuperUser.com.

Comment: moved it. http://superuser.com/questions/1128288/ffmpeg-stops-generating-mp4-1-5-seconds-before-end. Thank you!